# Nlog and how to present credentials in order to open a remote log file

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

Is there a way to enter Active Directory credential when targeting a file?

On my company, there are multiple applications writing to a single log file with info like start, success or error. I'd like create a new target on my nlog.config file but the file is remote and requires user and password.

Is that possible in Nlog or should I go with the traditional classes of File and Impersonator?

Thanks,
m0dest0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `ImpersonatingWrapper`:

```
<target xsi:type="ImpersonatingWrapper"
          name="wrapper1"
          userName="user1"
          password="tooDifficultPassword"
          revertToSelf="false"
          impersonationLevel="Impersonation"
          domain="Domain1"
          logOnType="Interactive"
          logOnProvider="Default">
    <target xsi:type="file" name="file1" />
```

For other options, check the [Wiki page of ImpersonatingWrapper](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/ImpersonatingWrapper-target)